# Is there a way to retrieve the Arabic data that have been saved in the database in a different encoding?

Tags: mysql, encoding, arabic, readable

I had made a form to record attendance, I tried it on local server, Arabic data was saved in the database correctly and I could read it clearly,
but When the form was published to public to enter their data, I was surprised that the data was saved in database like this ( Ø­Ø³Ø§Ù… ØµØ¯ÙŠÙ‚ )
so, my question is: Is there a way to display this data in a readable way?

i tried to change charset with connection like this mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");
it goes from ( Ø­Ø³Ø§Ù… ØµØ¯ÙŠÙ‚ ) to
( Ã™ÂÃ™Å Ã˜ÂµÃ™â€ž Ã™â€¦Ã˜Â­Ã™â€¦Ã˜Â¯ Ã˜Â¹Ã˜Â¨Ã˜Â¯ Ã˜Â§Ã™â€žÃ™â€žÃ™â€¡ Ã˜Â¹Ã™â€žÃ™Å )

Comment: Yes, there is. You can set the character set to be used per connection. What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: i tried this mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");  and it didn't work @Nico Haase

Comment: It's a _double_  [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case: `'حسام صديق'.encode( 'utf-8').decode( 'cp1252')` returns `'Ø\xadØ³Ø§Ù… ØµØ¯ÙŠÙ‚'` (stage 1)  and  `'حسام صديق'.encode( 'utf-8').decode( 'cp1252').encode( 'utf-8').decode( 'cp1252')` returns `'Ã˜Â\xadÃ˜Â³Ã˜Â§Ã™â€¦ Ã˜ÂµÃ˜Â¯Ã™Å\xa0Ã™â€š'` (stage 2). Examples in _Python_.